Calculate new labels based on existing label
I'm trying to compensate for a terrible data source I cant change.
It outputs a list of 45 metrics per device
outletStatus{deviceStatusIndex="1", ...} 4268
outletStatus{deviceStatusIndex="2", ...} 4257
...
outletStatus{deviceStatusIndex="45", ...} 4223

There's exactly 45 of these metrics with labels in the range from 1 to 45. In this current form its pretty useless for a user to look at as they would constantly need to recalculate the correct values.
What I'm looking for is some reasonable way in prometheus to recalculate or relabel or anything to take the following form.
outletStatus{deviceStatusIndex="1", deviceStatusPhase="1", ...} 4268
outletStatus{deviceStatusIndex="1", deviceStatusPhase="2", ...} 4257
...
outletStatus{deviceStatusIndex="15", deviceStatusPhase="3", ...} 4223

